# Access Query first 255 characters from text field

Tags: ms-access-2016

Hi Folks hope you can help.

I am using access 2016.
I have a table with a field that contains more than 255 characters. In the table the field is set as Long Text. When I run a query on the table the **FIRST** 255 characters are missing from the result. Has anyone come across this issue and had a successful resolution.

Many Thanks

Comment: Cross posted here  ? https://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=301887

Comment: So you phrased it wrongly? It was not the first 255 characters that were missing but the remainder?

Comment: No Gustav, the question was phrased correctly. The first 255 characters in the field were missing. When the unique values parameter was changed from 'Yes' to 'No' the field was fully populated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common issue. Please have a read here for reasons and workarounds.

http://allenbrowne.com/ser-63.html